# batch file cannot be run on non-system-drive Windows 2012R2

Tags: r, windows, batch-file, server

If I install any programs on non-system-drive (e.g. D drive - Windows 2012R2) 
e.g. R I cannot run the following batch/command:

```
"D:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2/bin/R.exe" --version 2>&1 | findstr /r "3.2."

'D:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What should I do?

Comment: The only way that error would display is if you did not have quotes around the entire path of the file.  Your code example does show it but are you really sure it is there in your batch file.

Comment: without and with quote have same error.

Comment: At the very minimum if the leading quote was in your command, it would show in the error output. So I am having a hard time believing it is in your code.

Comment: Why is the direction of slashes changing in the middle of the path?

Comment: The directory separator on Windows is ``\`` and `/` is used for options. So I suggest to use `"D:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\R.exe" --version 2>&1 | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "3.2."`. You know that `/R` means regular expression? It looks like `3.2.` is a literal string and therefore `/L` would be perhaps better.